# Understanding parameters in a function

Tags: bash, syntax, command

I found this function:

```
findsit()
{
    OPTIND=1
    local case=""
    local usage="findsit: find string in files.
Usage: fstr [-i] \"pattern\" [\"filename pattern\"] "
    while getopts :it opt
    do
        case "$opt" in
        i) case="-i " ;;
        *) echo "$usage"; return;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "$usage"
        return;
    fi
    find . -type f -name "${2:-*}" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 egrep --color=always -sn ${case} "$1" 2>&- | more 
}
```

I understand the output and what it does, but there are some terms I still don't understand and find it hard to find a reference, but believe they would be useful to learn in my programming. Can anyone quickly explain them? Some don't have man pages.

local

getopts

case

shift

$#

${2:-*}

2>&-

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **local**: Local variable. Let's say you had a variable called `foo` in your program. You call a function that also has a variable `foo`. Let's say the function changes the value of `foo`.

Try this program:

```
testme()
{
    foo="barfoo"
    echo "In function: $foo"
}

foo="bar"
echo "In program: $foo"
testme
echo "After function in program: $foo"
```

Notice that the value of `$foo` has been changed by the function even after the function has completed. By declaring `local foo="barfoo"` instead of just `foo="barfoo"`, we could have prevented this from happening.

- **case**: A case statement is a way of specifying a list of options and what you want to do with each of those options. It is sort of like an if/then/else statement.

These two are more or less equivelent:

```
if [[ "$foo" == "bar" ]]
then
   echo "He said 'bar'!"
elif [[ "$foo" == "foo" ]]
then
  echo "Don't repeat yourself!"
elif [[ "$foo" == "foobar" ]]
then
  echo "Shouldn't it be 'fubar'?"
else
   echo "You didn't put anything I understand"
fi
```

and

```
case $foo in
    bar)
        echo "He said 'bar'!"
        ;;
    foo)
        echo "Don't repeat yourself!"
        ;;
    foobar)
        echo "Shouldn't it be 'fubar'?"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "You didn't put anything I understand"
        ;;
esac
```

The `;;` ends the `case` option. Otherwise, it'll drop down to the next one and execute those lines too. I have each option in three lines, but they're normally combined like

```
foobar) echo "Shouldn't it be 'fubar'?";;
```

- **shift**: The command line arguments are put in the variable called `$*`. When you say `shift`, it takes the first value in that `$*` variable, and deletes it.
- **getopts**: Getopts is a rather complex command. It's used to parse the value of single letter options in the `$@` variable (which contains the parameters and arguments from the command line). Normally, you employ `getopts` in a while loop and use `case` statement to parse the output. The format is `getopts <options> var`. The `var` is the variable that will contain each option one at a time. The  specify the single letter parameters and which ones require an argument. The best way to explain it is to show you a [simple example](http://www.livefirelabs.com/unix_tip_trick_shell_script/may_2003/05262003.htm).
- **$#**: The number of parameters/arguments on the command line.
- **${var:-alternative}**: This says to use the value of the environment variable `$var`. However, if this environment variable is not set or is null, use the value `alternative` instead. In this program ${2:-*} is used instead. The `$2` represents the second parameter of what's left in the command line parameters/arguments after everything has been shifted out due to the `shift` command.
- **2>&-**: This moves Standard Error to Standard Output. Standard Error is where error messages are put. Normally, they're placed on your terminal screen just like Standard Output. However, if you redirect your output into a file, error messages are still printed to the terminal window. In this case, redirecting the output to a file will also redirect any error messages too.

Answer (score 2):

Those are bash built-ins. You should read the bash man page or, for getopts, try help getopts

One at a time (it's really annoying to type on ipad hence switched to laptop):

`local` lets you define local variables (within the scope of a function)

`getopts` is a bash builtin which implements getopt-style argument processing (the `-a`, `-b`... type arguments)

`case` is the bash form for a switch statement.  The syntax is

```
case: case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMANDS ;;]... esac
```

`shift` shifts all of the arguments by 1 (so that the second argument becomes the first, third becomes second, ...) similar to perl shift.  If you specify an argument, it will shift by that many indices (so `shift 2` will assign `$3 -> $1, $4 -> $2, ...`)

`$#` is the number of arguments passed to the function

`${2:-*}` is a default argument form.  Basically, it looks at the second argument (`$2` is the second arg) and if it is not assigned, it will replace it with `*`.

`2>&-` is output redirection (in this case, for standard error)

Comment: Thank you. Where can I read about those $# ${2:-*} and 2>&- and the like to understand them? The tip about "help" was useful, but in those cases "help" what?

Comment: I found the O'Reilly book *Learning the bash Shell* a good introduction to these things.

Comment: those variables are not covered in the help.  You have to look at the manpage: `man bash`.  the subsection "Special Parameters" explains what `$#` is: "       #      Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal."  The `${2:-*}` jazz is called "Parameter Expansion", and the relevant clause is "       `${parameter:-word}`" Use  Default  Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of  parameter is substituted.  As for the redirection, read the section "REDIRECTION"

Comment: @Tom the definitive guide is the manpage.  It's very thorough.

Comment: @Foo Bah - I've always found it hard to locate specific subjects in the manpage, and I certainly wouldn't recommend it for learning about bash.